# Execute a function right after user has chosen a file through tkFileDialog

Tags: python, tkinter, filedialog

I'm developing an interface  with Tkinter that makes use of a file dialog with `tkFileDialog`.
I want to run a function immediately after the user has chosen a file from the dialog box.

With buttons, we have a command keyword from which we run a function (usually named `def callback():`). Is there a similar keyword for the file dialog or `askopenfilename`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `askopenfilename` function consists of the opening of a dialog, and returns immediately when the latter was closed (including when a file has been selected).
Put your callback right after this function to have it run right after the closing of the dialog.

For instance:

```
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfile

fileDescriptor = askopenfilename()
print(fileDescriptor)
```

will open a file selection dialog, and as soon as the user has selected a file, the corresponding object that was created will be printed out.